# MDADM Chunk values

Tags: mdadm

I've a RAID 10 array made up of two SSDs using mdadm on linux,

I created it with

```
mdadm --create --verbose --level=10 --metadata=1.2 --chunk=512 --raid-devices=2 --layout=f2 /dev/md/MyRAID10Array /dev/nvme0n1p3 /dev/nvme1n1p3
```

but I'm wondering why when I look at the array I get a chunk size of 65536kb? I'm also thinking that --chunk=512 might be too big.

From cat /proc/mdstat

```
md127 : active raid10 nvme1n1p3[1] nvme0n1p3[0]
      942664704 blocks super 1.2 512K chunks 2 far-copies [2/2] [UU]
      [=====>...............]  resync = 29.5% (278703616/942664704) finish=55.2min speed=200170K/sec
      bitmap: 6/8 pages [24KB], 65536KB chunk
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the mdadm wiki at https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Mdstat, what you're looking at there is the bitmap chunk, not the array chunk. The size of the array chunk is 512K, just as you set it, according to the message two lines above that. While the wiki is not exactly clear on the meaning of the bitmap chunk value, it does say "The in-memory bitmap uses 16 bits for each bitmap chunk to count all ongoing writes to the chunk, so it's actually up to 16 times larger than the on-disk bitmap." It's possible that the "bitmap chunk" is actually the size of one "page" of bitmap in memory. Your array is reporting only 8 pages of bitmap, of which 6 are loaded into memory; once your resync completes, the page count for the bitmap should go down.

Answer (score 0):

`chunk` define the RAID array element stripe (ie: how big are the pieces - chunks - of data). From the [man page:](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mdadm.8.html)

```
-c, --chunk=
              Specify chunk size in kilobytes.  The default when
              creating an array is 512KB.
```

This is confirmed by `mdstat` 2nd line:

```
942664704 blocks super 1.2 *512K chunks* 2 far-copies [2/2] [UU]
```

Data chunks are different from *bitmap* chunks, which define the active zones covered by each bitmap's bit. These kind of chunks are much bigger - 64MB in your case:

```
bitmap: 6/8 pages [24KB], *65536KB chunk*
```

In general, for a RAID1/10 you don't need to tune these parameters. However, keep in mind that the defaults are optimized for rotational medias (HDDs) rather than fast SSD so, if you want, you can experiment with smaller data chunks (ie: 8-64K). I would not bother tuning the bitmap, though.